# Excel random value from a string containing substrings

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula, textjoin

I have this table that is defined as "Table1".

[image]

I also have a string which contains substrings inside it with delimiter ", " (comma + space)

I would like to get a formula to get one of those substrings **randomly**.

Excel version: Excel 365

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use FILTERXML to split the string and INDEX with RANDBETWEEN to randomly select one of the items:

```
=LET(valarr,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),INDEX(valarr,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(valarr))))
```

You can change the `A2` to `[@string containing substring]` for the structured reference.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use `MID` and `SEQUENCE` to find the words:

```
=LET(
    Txt, "Apple, Orange, Banana, Peach",
    Delim, ",",

    Seq, SEQUENCE(LEN(Txt)),
    TxtArr, MID(Txt, Seq, 1),
    StartArr, FILTER(Seq, (TxtArr = ",") + (Seq = 1)),
    EndArr, FILTER(Seq, (TxtArr = ",") + (Seq = LEN(Txt))),
    LenArr, EndArr - StartArr + 1,
    WordArr, TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(Txt, StartArr, LenArr), Delim, "")),
    INDEX(WordArr, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(WordArr)))
)
```

This creates an array of all string characters called `TxtArr`, then uses `Filter` to find the delimiters. `StartArr` (also) includes the first index and `EndArr` also includes the last index. `LenArr` is the approximate length of each word. Using `TRIM` and `SUBSTITUTE` removes the delimiter and any extra spaces.